# Partner Community Login Issues

Tags: partner-communities, partner-portal, partner

I don't understand, why can't I login to partner community? I used to login without issues.

The loading spinner is shown, and I can see some JS errors in Javascript console

[image]

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue? I've come across this [post](https://twitter.com/all_in_sfdc/status/1627573603150561280) today

Comment: I have opened a case in SF Support and they suggested a workaround

Answer (score 1):

I have opened a SF Support Case.

SF Support specialist suggested the following steps as a workaroud

- Open an incognito window
- Go to https://partners.salesforce.com
- Click on "Become a Partner a partner"
- Hit on "Join the Partner Community"
- Click on "Login with Salesforce" and type in your credentials
- Note: If you use SSO to login, click on "Use custom domain" and type in your firm's domain header
- And on the screen that says you are already a partner and have a Partner Community access click "Go to partner community"